# Artifactory and multiple docker repositories with nginx using embedding the repository name in the image name

Tags: artifactory, docker-registry

Inspired by this article https://www.jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-access-multiple-artifactory-docker-repositories-from-a-single-url/ we have configured multiple docker repositories on artifactory using nginx as reverse proxy.

There are three docker repositories accessible:

- docker.acme.com  (artifactoryhost/artifactory/docker/default)
- docker.acme.com/repository-a (artifactoryhost/artifactory/docker/repository-a)
- docker.acme.com/repository-b (artifactoryhost/artifactory/docker/repository-b)

All three repos have their own users with the permissions.

Pull is fine, but push to repository-a or repository-b do not work properly if user is not allowed to push to default repository. All uploads during the push are stored in the default repository first and only at the end they are moved to repository-a.

As I can see in artifactory logs, when I'm pushing something like

`docker push docker.acme.com/repository-a/myimage:1.0.0`

docker does some POST requests, receives from artifactory upload locations and proceeds with PATCH to upload layers. But responses from artifactory do not contain any repository path in the Location:

```
2017/11/08 12:35:17 [debug] 19310#0: *6107899 http upstream request: 
"/artifactory/api/docker/repository-a/v2/myimage/blobs/uploads/?
from=repository-
a%2Fmyimage&mount=sha256%3A6a8bd10c9278a8e1b59bc85f634dd4045e953
63c3b29366e9e8200ac2cd56735"
2017/11/08 12:35:17 [debug] 19310#0: *6107899 http upstream process 
header
2017/11/08 12:35:17 [debug] 19310#0: *6107899 malloc: 
0000000000EA8EF0:4096
2017/11/08 12:35:17 [debug] 19310#0: *6107899 recv: fd:23 427 of 4096
2017/11/08 12:35:17 [debug] 19310#0: *6107899 http proxy status 202 
"202 Accepted"
2017/11/08 12:35:17 [debug] 19310#0: *6107899 http proxy header: 
"Server: Artifactory/5.0.1"
2017/11/08 12:35:17 [debug] 19310#0: *6107899 http proxy header: "X-
Artifactory-Id: 1cfb2a5a96486c54:43202ab7:15ced9e7676:-8000"
2017/11/08 12:35:17 [debug] 19310#0: *6107899 http proxy header: 
"Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0"
2017/11/08 12:35:17 [debug] 19310#0: *6107899 http proxy header: 
"Docker-Upload-Uuid: d0d4ed31-6539-43a3-bb03-35e47fa13676"
2017/11/08 12:35:17 [debug] 19310#0: *6107899 http proxy header: 
"Location: https://docker.acme.com/v2/myimage/blobs/uploads/d0d4ed31-
6539-43a3-bb03-35e47fa13676"
```

and thus all next PATCHes are going to the default repo but not to the repository-a.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

Nginx appears to be enforcing the ["Internet Hosts" RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) to some extent (also see [this wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_hostnames)), and would [reject](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/ngx_http_request.c#L2010) any Host headers that contain illegal characters in them, such as the slash character with a 400 response code. The article you referenced uses Apache, which does not appear to have similar restrictions on the Host header. You might be able to workaround this by finding a different character to use to separate the repository name in the Host header while still keeping it valid. This will obviously require adjustments in the reverse proxy configuration as well, particularly, for the part where the response Location header is being modified as explained below.
However, I should have mentioned from the beginning that this solution is definitely a hack and probably not the most robust solution anyway, as it piggybacks on undocumented API behavior with Docker V2 repositories in Artifactory. It is particularly useful for users who cannot set up [a flexible subdomain-based mechanism for docker repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy#ConfiguringaReverseProxy-UsingSubdomain), because they are not able to use a wildcard certificate, for example. That said, if you haven't done so already, you should at least consider using one of the two documented options [in this page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

It looks like the original POST request's "Host" header might not include the repository name in it, otherwise Artifactory would have included the physical repository name in the Location header of the response. The solution you referred to requires the Host header to be in the format of $host/$repo, i.e:

Host: docker.acme.com/repository-a

Artifactory then constructs the Location header for the PATCH endpoint using this information. Here's a reproduction case with curl:

**Good** request:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Host: docker.acme.com/repository-a" "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/docker/repository-a/v2/myimage/blobs/uploads/?from=repository-a%2Fmyimage&mount=sha256%3A6a8bd10c9278a8e1b59bc85f634dd4045e95363c3b29366e9e8200ac2cd56735" -v
```

**Good** Location header in the response:

```
Location: https://docker.acme.com/repository-a/v2/myimage/blobs/uploads/fc325614-0e65-4c9a-a879-449ac9e8c66
```

A **bad** request would be:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Host: docker.acme.com" https://...
```

Note that the Location header has the "v2" and "repoName" elements in reversed order to how the Apache server would intercept them. The trick here is to change the order on the Apache config by editing the Location header of the response:

```
Header edit* Location "^https://<apache-server-name>/(.*?)/v2/(.*)$" "https://<apache-server-name>:<port#>/v2/$1/$2"
```

HTH,

Comment: Extending the host header with repository path does not work for me:
artifactory respond:

`"400 Bad Request"`

Comment: @abinet is this with curl or with Docker? make you sure the Host header is in the format of "hostname/repoName". Do not include the scheme or anything else. Try and see whether the request that gets responded with a 400 is routed to where it should be routed in Artifactory using the artifactory request.log file - if it does, you might have something in the Host header that isn't valid, or Apache itself might be returning a 400. Feel free to submit a ticket @ support@jfrog.com and reference this thread so I can pick it up - be sure to include both your apache/artifactory logs and apache config.

Comment: I've tried both curl and Docker. As soon as I put repo-name into Host header I get "400 Bad request".
Artifactory request.log doesn't contain any entries for this, but access.log gets "[DENIED LOGIN]  for NA/<ip of my nginx>"

Maybe I did not mark this explicit enough but I'm using **nginx** as reverse proxy.

Comment: I misread that, apologies. Apparently, nginx enforces the Host RFC to some extent, and would reject Host headers that contain a slash or other illegal characters in them [1][2]. I will update my answer to contain that information along with possible alternatives. [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_hostnames [2] https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/ngx_http_request.c#L2010